# How to handle potentially NSFW yet valid images

Tags: discussion, etiquette, images

This question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283074/identify-cervix-region-from-cervicogram) contains a link to a medical image of a cervix that users might not want to show up at work. However, it is a perfectly valid image for this question (even if it is a poor question in this case) which is about writing code to process this image.

What is the correct protocol in this situation? Adding the image to question (what I would normally do when a new user posts a link to an image) seems like a bad choice as I know I personally wouldn't want this image displaying while I was at work.

Should I leave the link and add a note that the image might be considered NSFW?

Comment: Related: [What is the criteria for an acceptable image?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92560/168244)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The user posted a link rather than an image, and that is the wise thing to do in this case. Also, I put in *NSFW* in the image link to make it obvious to users what to expect when they click.

While it is indeed a horrible question, the image does support the case, so removing it doesn't seem right. I have seen other communities even use *NSFW* in the post title so that might be a possibility too.

Comment: I think that the link should be changed to something a bit clearer like [Medical image - potentially NSFW](http://www.google.com)

Comment: I agree on that. Updated.

Comment: Also, if you really fear the link may root, you can include the image in the post while writing it, then remove the image and use the stack imgur url generated from the "fake" upload. Patrick, you may add this suggestion to your reply to increase its visibility if you like.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean @Derpy

Comment: If you add the image to the post, a revision entry will be generated with a stack.imgur.com version of the image. You can then replace the direct link with the stack.imgur.com link and minimize the possibility of link rot.

Comment: I thought the images were already from the `i.stack` Imgur account.

Comment: It was supposed to be a more general suggestion, not limited to this specific post. If your image link is an external one, you may want to do a fake upload to the stack.imgur.com account and then use the generated link. That way, you are sure that the picture link won't root.

Comment: @Derpy One other way to make the image eternal is to actually keep that edit with the image in it - and then re-edit it immediately. Image eternalized in the edit history. Obviously it does take full editing privileges to do this right.

Answer (score 2):

We have spoiler blocks for this, and they also work on images.

> [image: You clicked!]

Move the mouse over the block above and the image shows up.

Since this still means the image may show up accidentally, you may want to just provide a link instead.

Comment: But this will show up in a mouse roll-over and there is nothing to warn people not to move their mouse over the spoiler tag. So at the very least I think this should include a clear warning. But I also feel that this makes it far to easy for someone to accidentally view the image while at work.

Comment: Spoilers on large images don't really work, but it is an option indeed. (tried on the original post and didn't really work)